# Bash. awk last column with possible spaces

Tags: bash, awk

I have a dynamic output. Like this sometimes:

```
F8:XX:94:XX:C2:XX    1    39%     No    ANY_NAME
A2:XX:34:XX:E8:XX    6    42%     Yes    ANY_OTHER_NAME
D1:XX:78:XX:A1:XX    6    24%     No    MORESTUFF
```

Or like this other times:

```
F8:XX:94:XX:C2:XX    1    433     39%     No    ANY NAME
A2:XX:34:XX:E8:XX    6    232     42%     No    ANY_OTHER_NAME
D1:XX:78:XX:A1:XX    6    112     22%     Yes    MORE STUFF
```

As you can see the last column is what I want but it can contain spaces or not and the number of columns is dynamic.

I need to capture the value of the last column always in case of having no spaces or having multiple spaces. Sometimes, the column number is dynamic too but the data I want is always in last place having spaces or not. The column before this data it's always a "Yes" or "No" (not sure if this can help).

Is there a way to do it with awk? This is what I have actually:

```
myvar=$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $NF}')
```

But with this is taking just the last part after a space, not the complete data. So this is working only if the data has no spaces.

What I want is to get always the last data complete with its spaces in case of containing them. Any help?

Comment: Is the column separator a tabulation or multiple spaces? In the second case, can you say that there will always be at least two spaces between columns, and at most one consecutive space in the last column's value?

Comment: can be both, spaces or tabs, it depends.

Comment: That's some badly formatted data ! Ignacio's answer should be fine though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for `\s` and `\S` shorthand:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^%]+%\s+\S+\s+/,"")}1' file
ANY_NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORESTUFF
ANY NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORE STUFF
oh   No     lots of    spaces
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^%]+%[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")}1' file
ANY_NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORESTUFF
ANY NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORE STUFF
oh   No     lots of    spaces
```

or with any sed that supports -E for EREs (e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD seds):

```
$ sed -E 's/[^%]+%[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+//' file
ANY_NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORESTUFF
ANY NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORE STUFF
oh   No     lots of    spaces
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
F8:XX:94:XX:C2:XX    1    39%     No    ANY_NAME
A2:XX:34:XX:E8:XX    6    42%     Yes    ANY_OTHER_NAME
D1:XX:78:XX:A1:XX    6    24%     No    MORESTUFF
F8:XX:94:XX:C2:XX    1    433     39%     No    ANY NAME
A2:XX:34:XX:E8:XX    6    232     42%     No    ANY_OTHER_NAME
D1:XX:78:XX:A1:XX    6    112     22%     Yes    MORE STUFF
D1:XX:78:XX:A1:XX    6    112     22%     Yes    oh   No     lots of    spaces
```

wrt your comments, here is the first script handling the input file contents being passed to it 1 line at a time from a pipe:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" | awk '{sub(/[^%]+%\s+\S+\s+/,"")}1'
done < file
ANY_NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORESTUFF
ANY NAME
ANY_OTHER_NAME
MORE STUFF
oh   No     lots of    spaces
```

All of the other scripts can be used exactly the same way.

Comment: checking your solution. it works if you create a file and it launchs it as you are doing, but what i need is an `echo "line-stuff" | magic-awk-stuff` and in that way is not working... I mean, an awk or sed command to be used after a pipe. It must be in this way. Any help? I really would like to use your solution which seems better to save double spacing.

Comment: Just do `cat file | awk 'script'` instead of `awk 'script' file`. Replace `cat file` with whatever your pipe is. If that's what you tried and it's `not working` then if you tell us in what way it's `not working` then there's a good chance we might be able to help you debug that issue.

Comment: But my program is doing it line by line... so I need echo "line-content" | awk-magic and it this way this is not working

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer about in what way it's "not working". Wrong output, no output, error message, core dump, what? There's absolutely nothing about any of the scripts in my answer that care if it's reading a file vs getting input from a pipe, or getting 1 million lines of input at a time or getting 1 line of input at a time. Edit your question to include a minimal, complete program that clearly demonstrates whatever problem you're having.

Comment: I need something to be used on each line to pass it using a pipe to the awk-magic-stuff . In my example of what I have i'm using the pipe. Anyway, thanks for your approach. For now the best answer for me is what is already marked as accepted answer. Sorry if it was not completely clear on the answer. I can change the accepted answer if you have a better approach. Thanks :)

Comment: Oscar - I believe I completely understand what you want and my script does exactly that. In that regard it behaves no differently than the script you had in your question nor the one in the accepted answer. Any of the scripts in my answer **IS** a better approach than the currently accepted answer. I have no idea what problem you could be experiencing and if you can't post a small, complete script to demonstrate the problem then I can't help you figure out what it is you're doing wrong.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis I just updated my answer to show one of the scripts being fed 1 line at a time from a pipe. What's wrong with that? How does it differ from what you're doing?

Comment: Ok I found what is happening. Is not your fault. Is because on real data sometimes the column with the percentage % has the % symbol and other times it hasn't it... and in that cases is failing :/ Sorry because in my example I put here I put the % always...

Comment: Ohhh and I see that on the column after the data I want not always is Yes or No... this is a hell of non-formatted data ¬¬

Comment: If you'd like help then post a new question with more truly representative sample input/output as this question has become too muddy and too old to now get any more attention, especially since you already accepted an answer yesterday. It doesn't sound like your data will actually be difficult to deal with (I can think of several alternatives to handle what you've told us so far, including in those most recent comments) but we've got to know what it really looks like to be able to provide the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure that the data you care about can never have a run of more than one space then use that as your field separator instead.

```
awk -F '\t| {2,}' ...
```

Comment: I'm testing it. It works for normal cases... but if the name has double space, for example "ANY[space][space]NAME" is not working. It could happen. Anyway, with your solution for now, is better than what I have.

Comment: I'll check your solution too. if is better i'll change my accepted answer, why not. Is known that with this solution a double space screw up the stuff. Upvoting anyway for all your contribution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk :

```
awk '{sub(/.*(Yes|No)[[:blank:]]*/,"")}1' infile
```

Comment: That will fail when `MORESTUFF` is `I said No Thank You` for example.

Comment: Yes, we can always find a way. Yours fail if it's a % before the 4th column.

Comment: Right but there's nothing in the question to indicate that can happen whereas the text at the end of each line is clearly just a placeholder for any text so there's no reason to think "No" or "Yes" cannot appear there. Obviously you can't cater to everything that might be completely different from what's in the posted sample input but when, as in this case, you see text in the provided example that indicates it can be any text then you should account for that when parsing it.